# Polynomial generator

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, operator-theory, pseudo-differential-operators

If we let $\alpha$ be a multiindex, can we generate any polynomial in $\eta$ with coefficients as multiples of $\kappa$ 
$$
D_z^{\alpha}\text{exp}(i(\kappa(z)-\kappa(x)-\kappa'(x)(z-x))\eta)|_{z=x}
$$
where $D=1/i \partial$, and $\kappa'$ denotes the jacobi matrix of $\kappa$, and where $\eta$ is an n-dimensional vector, and $\kappa$ is a diffeomorphism between two open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. 
I'm asking based on the second-to-last line in a proof in M.A. Shubin, where he speaks about the "universality" of these polynomials, namely the last line of theorem 4.2 in Pseudodifferential Operators and Spectral Theory.